# Сборка MySQL Connector/C++: отладочная версия

Tags: c++, mysql, сборка, mysqlconnector

Не могу собрать MySQL Connector/C++ win32 debug.

Версия boost:1.66
Версия cmake:3.10.1
Source Connector/C++:1.1.9 c github

Запускаю командой `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DMYSQL_DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1"` (Boost находит через глобальную, а директория MySQL будет указывает на Connector C 6.11.1).

У первого запуска был warning: mysqlcppconn.sln имеет отличную политику от CMP0022:

```
CMake Warning (dev) in driver/CMakeLists.txt:
Policy CMP0022 is not set: INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES defines the link
interface.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0022" for policy details.  Use the
cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "mysqlcppconn" has an INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property which
differs from its LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES properties.

INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES:

mysqlclient;ws2_32

LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES:

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Изменил в CMakeList ее на 0022 (Была 0003).

Собралось.

Далее командой `devenv MYSQLCPPCONN.sln /build Release` поставил собираться. Не вышло.

```
========== Сборка: успешно: 17, с ошибками: 18, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 2 ==========
```

Пытался собрать dev версию, там еще хуже.

А все началось из-за того, что у меня происходит ошибка из типового примера с сайта MySQL, а именно:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn\driver.h>
#include <cppconn\exception.h>
#include <cppconn\resultset.h>
#include <cppconn\statement.h>
#include <cppconn\prepared_statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message'..." << endl;

    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://**:3306", "*", "**");
        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("skud");

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");

        while (res->next()) {
            cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
            /* Access column data by alias or column name */
            cout << res->getString("_message") << endl; //Ошибка доступа, до этого все хорошо идет
            cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
            /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
            cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
        }
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;

    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Плюс куча предупреждений С4251: *"такой-то" объект должен иметь dll-интерфейс чтобы использовать "такое"*. Сижу и мучаюсь, вполне возможно придется качать прошлые версии Boost, но вот ошибка с cmake не нравится. Жду предложений.

**P.S.** Отладочная версия x86 жизненно необходима, ибо одна из библиотек, которые я использую написана на C++ win32 и с этим нечего сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу на свой вопрос:

1. Сборка *Connector/C++* версий 1.* не гарантируется для 140v тулсета и выше. Следует использовать 120v;
2. Лучше начать переходить на *X protocol* для MySQL, но тут 2 проблемы:

   - Вроде как следует настроить шифрованное соединение с БД (Про **обязательно** ни слова, но акцент на шифрование явный);
   - Версии 8.0.* не стабильны, 8.0.5 собрал без проблем, а с 8.0.6 собрал, но куча ошибок словил после подключения к проекту;
3. Отсюда следует, что синтаксис использования изменится и подниматься минимальная используемая версия *MySQL Server* (Для *X protocol* - это 5.7.12);
4. Гайды на официальном сайте про *Connector/C++* сильно устарели, так как ошибки сборки случаются часто и для 120v тулсета даже если идти чисто по гайду.